# ComboBox push the controls under it

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

Like any combobox in WP when the combobox is opened (expanded) it pushes the controls under it down.
In my app when it is opened some of it is hidden because another control is over it.
How can i make all the controls goes down when the combo box is opened.
I want to make like this
[image: Right ComboBox]

What i have is like this

[image: what i have]

--EDIT
My xaml Code is

```
<Grid x:Name="addingBabyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="323">
            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0.9"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="41" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303"/>
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="53" Width="298" RequestedTheme="Light" Background="Black">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Male"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Female"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <DatePicker Width="293" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="Black" BorderBrush="#FF7E7E7E" RequestedTheme="Light"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Post your 'XAML code'

Comment: wpf? winforms? asp? you find the difference in height of the combobox and add that to the below controls. in some technologies you can even anchor controls to the one above it

Comment: @Sayse From the pic i assume its a windows phone application

Comment: @Sajeetharan - The pictures were broken when I posted the comment, as were the new tags.

Comment: Yes sure it is a windows phone app

Comment: i posted my xaml code

Comment: **--EDIT My xaml Code for the combobox is !** I dont see any code

Comment: Post the code for other controls too!

Comment: Here it is Sajeetharan
Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you should be using is the ListPicker from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone for the task you need. Also, your issue is mostly that you have set the height of the ComboBox explicitly, which does not allow it to show the other items.

See my code that works as you want:

```
<Grid x:Name="addingBabyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="323">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="41" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303"/>
    <wpToolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="298">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Male"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Female"/>
    </wpToolkit:ListPicker>
    <DatePicker Width="293" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Background="Black" BorderBrush="#FF7E7E7E" RequestedTheme="Light"/>
</Grid>
```

Generally, when using controls like StackPanel and Grid, you do not want to set the height and width of an element, but leave them to be automatically set by either the container, the controls content or both.